# How can I reload the current page in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I currently have a login popup in my header bar which is on every page in my website.  I want to be able to reload the current page that the person is on after a successful login.  How do I do this in the controller?

```
def create
  #declaring and defining user variable stuff
  if user.save
    #reload current page <--how do I do this?
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: This is an answer that can be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8619748/1770571

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For my application, I use `redirect_to :back` and it does the trick. However, I doubt this might have an error in a non general use case(s) (user came from a special page?) but i haven't found it so far in my app.

Comment: This works for me to.  You aren't reloading the current page, as much as you are going to a create action and then back again... If you use AJAX, then you'd just update the part where you show a dude's logged in... and keep him on that page.

Comment: Documentation for redirect_to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Comment: For Rails 5, `redirect_to :back` has been deprecated to be removed in 5.1, and instead `redirect_back(fallback_location: fallback_location)` should be used.

Answer (score 51):

If you're looking for a way to get the page to refresh (typically `redirect_to :back`) with an XHR request, you don't have to look for a way to change the response type - just tell the page to reload with inline JS.

`format.js { render inline: "location.reload();" }`

Like [Elena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792916/elena-g-washington) mentions, this should go in a respond_to block, like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
end
```

Comment: Cannot upvote this enough times!

Answer (score 29):

In Rails 5 `redirect_to :back` [is improved](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/29/rails-5-improves-redirect_to_back-with-redirect-back.html) by:

```
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```

Comment: It works well with Rails 6 in 2020, btw `redirect_to :back` seem does not work for me

Comment: Worth noting that flash messages work with this method too, e.g.: `redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: "Job done"`

Answer (score 20):

Since Rails 5 (or maybe older versions), you have a `request.referrer` method. You simply redirect from controller to referrer and it opens the page where request came from.

`redirect_to request.referrer, notice: "You're being redirected"`

Answer (score 17):

[Archonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1686604/archonic)'s answer above worked for me. However, in Rails 3, I had to place this in a `respond_to` block in order to avoid an 'ArgumentError (too few arguments)' error:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Rails 5 introduced alternative function:

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```

It redirect back whenever the HTTP_REFERER is known. 
Otherwise it redirects to the fallback_location.

The `redirect_to :back` is deprecated in Rails 5.0 https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22506 and removed since Rails 5.1

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is what you want... works in Rails 6

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to request.referrer, notice: "User was successfully WHATEVER." }
  end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This solution works perfectly for my rails 6 application! Where did you happen to come across this method? It took quite a bit of looking for me.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Archonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1686604/archonic)'s and [Elena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792916/elena-g-washington)'s Answers, the reload function accepts a parameter to force the page to reload from the server aka [forceGet](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp), instead of from cache.  A parameter can be set by the controller logic, like successful or failed login of a user, to trigger the desired behavior when it is sent to the page.

```
# force_get = controller_logic ? true : false

respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render inline: "location.reload(#{force_get});" }
end
```

**UPDATE:**
the logic has been deprecated for the forceGet option.  If you do want to reload from the server you can use this logic:

```
# force_get = controller_logic ? true : false

respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render inline: force_get ? "window.location.href = window.location.href;" : "location.reload();" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

just redirect to whatever url you want in the function:

redirect_to what_ever_path