# Action that refreshes the current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, action

I want to create an action in a Rails controller that does something in the db and then just refreshes the current page.

Example:
Controller: A
Views: A, B.

controller A is the following:

```
def action1
    somethingToTheDB
end
```

view A is the following:

```
-html-
-body--link to action 1--/body-
-/html-
```

view B is the following

```
-html-
-body--link to action 1--/body-
-/html-
```

If I come to action 1 from view A I want to refresh view A, if I come from view 2 I want to refresh view 2. Is that possible without passing a parameter in the link to indicate the view that must be rendered?

Thanks

Comment: I don't follow.  It might be useful to present more of the actual code, if it exists.  The way you've presented the question, I would expect to see the view `action1.html.haml` or similar -- not `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure to catch your question but can't you just do:

```
def action_1
  # something_to_the_db
  redirect_to :back
end
```

If you need to access your `controller_name` and `action_name` in your `action_1` for whatever reason:

```
<%= link_to 'Refresh' refresh_path(:aktion => action_name, 
                                   :kontroller => controller_name) %>
```

`aktion` and `kontroller` aren't typo. You have to write them like that, otherwise, it will clash.

`action_name` and `controller_name` are variables. Write them like that.

It will look like something like that (depending on what's your `refresh_path`, your current controller and your current action):

```
<a href="/refresh?aktion=index&kontroller=articles">Refresh</a>
```

Then in your controller:

```
def action_1
  kontroller = params[:kontroller]
  aktion     = params[:aktion]
  # Do whatever you want in the db
  redirect_to :controller => kontroller, :action => aktion
  # or redirect_to :back (better IMO)
end
```

Comment: Indeed, just `redirect_to :back` will return to the referrer.

Comment: @nathanvda That's what I initially thought but maybe he needs to do something particular in the db based on the referrer... But again, `redirect_to :back` will execute the initial query so... Not sure to understand his question, waiting for a reaction from him ;)

Comment: I need to access my controller and action, so I think this is the answer.

Comment: I'm a Rails newb, so be gentle: Wouldn't this solution allow anyone to format a URL that performs any action on any controller? Like: /refresh?aktion=destroy&kontroller=articles