# How to create simple refresh page link with Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fairly new to ruby on rails, and am experimenting with the structure and functionality of RoR and want to know how to create a simple reload link using RoR instead of the static HTML way

Comment: You want reload the current page or redirect  it to other?

Comment: reload the current page sorry

Comment: it will be good if you can add it in the javascript rather than in your rails code. in rails you can do redirect_to :back

Comment: Use `link_to(params)`

Comment: I have a list of URL's that RoR fires off and presents the response code from the given URL's so I can quickly present environments that are up or down etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465259/ruby-on-rails-reload-current-page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
link_to "reload", url_for(params)
```

Comment: An attacker can send someone else a link and that way decide the arguments for `url_for`. That can probably be used to make the "reload" link do stuff it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you just do an empty string for the url: 
`<%= link_to "Refresh", "" %>`, that will link back to current page. Assuming you want to clear the params.

If you want a refresh with the params then do as @bubblez answered:

`<%= link_to "Refresh", url_for(params) %>`.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to keep it doing with Javascript. Rails could help you in case you want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you want to just reload the page. (Probably need a bit more context) but you could just generate a link on the page that will reload it like this:

```
<%= link_to "reload", root_path %>
```

That will just output a link to the root_path, you can redirect back to whatever page you are currently on by changing the second parameter in the link_to helper. For list of routes, run "rake routes".

Comment: I have a list of URL's that RoR fires off and presents the response code from the given URL's so I can quickly present environments that are up or down etc

Comment: What do you mean by fires off? Are you doing this asynchronously?

Comment: Well I am using Net:HTTP to go to the URL I have defined and present back the response code next to the URL

Comment: Okay, starting to make more sense.. So you want the page to just reload and essentially refresh all of these statuses?

Comment: If thats the case, I would go for a simple link_to call  with a path back to your current page, or simply do it through JS

Comment: What is your current controller and controller action that renders this view?