# Rails auto reload page when some record change?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app, some pages show data from DB, does any way that when I change specify DB record(almost use phone app calls web API),and if my web idle on page which related the change data, the specify page will `auto reload or refresh?` does it can use `ajax` or `javascript` to achieve?

I use rails 4.2.2 & mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your model, use the following code:

```
class MyModel
  after_update :reload_page

  def reload_page
    ### Code to reload page
  end
end
```

The `after_update` attribute means whenever a record changes(changes committed), the `reload_page` method will be called.

Also, you might take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465259/how-can-i-reload-the-current-page-in-ruby-on-rails) that shows how to refresh a page.

In case you want to use an API or do the same thing in a controller, do:

```
class MyController
  after_filter :reload_page, :only => :update

  def reload_page
    ### Code to reload page
  end
end
```

That way, whenever `MyController#update`method is called, `reload_page` will be executed.

Comment: but I use API to change data, how do I set the reload_page? if my website have have pageA, I want to refresh only pageA when data change(there are other method will change other data columns)